# Internet speed reduces when cat5e wires are joined together

Tags: speed, cat5e

Why does the internet speed reduces to 100mps from 1000mps when the join 2 cat5e cables together. It also does that when I use a wall ethernet outlet. If the cable is continuous without any joins then the speed stays up to 1000mps

Answer (score 3):

Loosing Gigabit speeds suggests that whatever device you are using to join the cables is not linking all 8 cores of the wire across, or at least not doing it correctly. Either one of the wires or connections is bad or the joining device is not made for Gigabit.

Gigabit Ethernet requires 4 pairs (8 wires) to work properly.

It might be that your Ethernet joiner is only connecting 4 wires, in which case you will be limited to 100mbps.

Likewise your wall plates might only have 4 wires connected. If it has two sockets then a lazy cabling engineer might have run only one cable and used 2 pairs (4 wires) for one socket and the other 2 pairs for the second socket. Again this would limit you to 100mbps.